# How to store generic struct in map with other struts with different generic types

Tags: go, generics

I am writing an RPC library and stumbled onto a problem I would like to fix with generics, because doing type asserts left and right is ugly.

How can I store a typed interface in a map with other structs of the same interface but different generic types?
Any workaround is ok, as long as I can do it without changing the `DMethod` interface. The `DMethod` interface should be as simple as possible, as that will be implemented everywhere.

I am using go1.21, if that makes a difference.

How far I got in the end (vastly simplified, but this shows my problem):

```golang
// The current method interface. I would like to get rid of the interfaces for request and response to save on type asserts.
type Method interface {
    Execute(ctx context.Context, req json.Unmarshaler) (json.Marshaler, error)
}

type DMethod[REQ json.Unmarshaler, RESP json.Marshaler] interface {
    Execute(ctx context.Context, req REQ) (RESP, error)
}

type DServer struct {
    // QUESTION: How can I make this map store the typed DMethod?
    methods map[string]interface{}
}

func (s *DServer) dRunServer() {
    // QUESTION: How do I get the correct method out of the map?
}
```

I also tried using a non-generic interface without generics as in-between thing:

```golang
type XMethod interface {
    Execute(ctx context.Context, req json.Unmarshaler) (json.Marshaler, error)
}

type DMethod[REQ json.Unmarshaler, RESP json.Marshaler] interface {
    Execute(ctx context.Context, req REQ) (RESP, error)
}

type DServer struct {
    methods map[string]XMethod
}

func (s *DServer) dRunServer() json.Marshaler {
    method := s.methods["example"]
    response, _ := method.Execute(context.Background(), &ExampleRequest{})
    return response
}

func dAddMethod[REQ json.Unmarshaler, RESP json.Marshaler](server *DServer, methodName string, method DMethod[REQ, RESP]) {
    // Does not compile
    server.methods[methodName] = XMethod(method)
}
```

I feel like I am close, but just cannot find the last bit I am missing.
I am open for non-generic ways to do it, but my currently working implementation already uses interfaces instead of the generics and having to constantly type assert is a chore.

Comment: Generics offer compile-time type specialization. Once those types are instantiated they cannot be changed. If you want runtime polymorphism you need to use interfaces.